# Facebook permissions required to tag a friend in a wall post..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to tag a friend in a post which I am posting on my wall , just wanted to know what permissions are required...?

I am using the following code...

For permissions..

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"friends_online_presence",
                                    @"read_stream",
                                    @"email",
                                    @"publish_stream",
                                    nil];
            [self.appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
            [permissions release];
```

and to post

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                               @"Test 2",@"message",
                               @"100004311843201,1039844409", @"to",
                               nil];

[self.appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

This gets posted on wall successfully but the profile ids are not included...

Comment: @Jennis I was able to tag people but that required a Place field attached to it. Without it I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please post your solution if possible and accept too so others can get help too (If you wish of course). Thax +1

Answer (score 3):

Though its in PHP [here is bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/395975667115722/) which says it is problem in Graph API while posting status update and tagging friends is not working properly.

It says that it will post status update but tagging is not working.

**EDIT:**

As discussed with OP in comments, adding place field attached to parameters it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you:

To mention a user in a user message, place this string inline with the message: @[userID] or @[profileUrl]. This creates an inline hyperlink to the profile of the mentioned friends and sends them a notification that they have been tagged.

Taken from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/mention-tagging/

Answer (score 0):

For tag friends in Facebook friends id are required to tag in post etc.

customer friend picker is better for tag friends.
see below Facebook sample
https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2178-6/851564_497226807066458_2037734970_n.png

for this purpose us this graph api [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends) to get tag able friends

for more detail visit this link and read tag section (Mention Tagging is suite for your requirements)
[mentiontagging detail info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process#actioncapabilities-mentiontagging)