# How to tag friends in your Facebook wall post...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to tag some of my friends in my wall post and I am sending the following parameters but this posts to my wall the FB ids I provide do not get attached to the post...

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                               @"Test 2  ",@"message",
                               @"100004311843201 , 1039844409", @"to",
                               @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                               @"Test", @"name",
                               nil];

[self.appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Why are you posting same question twice??
You already have asked the same question at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985466/facebook-permissions-required-to-tag-a-friend-in-a-wall-post/13985899#13985899

Comment: @AkshayShah that was regarding permissions..

Comment: You had mentioned the same thing there too... It would be better to edit that question, instead of creating another question..

Answer (score 0):

To tag a friend in ur fb status ..you need "facebook id" of your friend by using FBFriendPickerViewController  and "place id" using FBPlacePickerViewController. 
Following code will help you.

```
  NSString *apiPath = nil;

apiPath = @"me/feed";



if(![self.selectedPlaceID isEqualToString:@""]) {

    [params setObject:_selectedPlaceID forKey:@"place"];

}

NSString *tag  = nil;
if(mSelectedFriends != nil){
    for (NSDictionary *user in mSelectedFriends) {
        tag = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"id"] ];

        [tags addObject:tag];

    }

    NSString *friendIdsSeparation=[tags componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSString *friendIds = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"[%@]",friendIdsSeparation ];

    [params setObject:friendIds forKey:@"tags"];
}

FBRequest *request = [[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:_fbSession graphPath:apiPath parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] autorelease];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error ===== %@",error.description);
        if (_delegate != nil) {
            [_delegate facebookConnectFail:error requestType:FBRequestTypePostOnWall];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Error ===== %@",error.description);
        }


    }else{

        if (_delegate != nil) {
            [_delegate faceboookConnectSuccess:self requestType:FBRequestTypePostOnWall];
        }
    }
```